# How to recognize a null sting

Tags: c#

I have a string `TempDayValues[j]` that holds a null value but the following two examples do not recognize the `null`

```
string Temp = TempDayValues[j].Trim();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Temp))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Found Null");
     TempDayValues[j] = TempDayValues[j - 1];
}

If(Temp == null)
{
   //code here
}
```

Is there any better way to recognize `null` values?

Comment: If you managed to perform `.Trim()` on the string without a `NullReference` then your string is not null. Maybe you are looking for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` - for null empty or white spaces?

Comment: Actually the first line should throw a NullReferenceException if the value behind [j] is null. Because you are calling `.Trim` on a null value. If it does not throw any exception, your value behind [j] obviously is not null.

Comment: This cannot be neither a null string or an empty string. If you call Trim on an null string you get an exception. And string.IsNullOrEmpty is the correct way to check for this case. So there is something different at work here. Use the debugger to check what is the value of Temp

Comment: You can use the null coalescing double question marks to test for nulls in a string or other nullable value type. But `string.isNullorEmpty` is the best and most widely used efficient way to check if a string is empty or null.

Comment: @GiladGreen Trim works on the same character set used by IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: @Steve - True - but I meant instead of first trimming and then checking - but just using `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` for both checking null and then checking if it is basically an empty string

Comment: Yes that code is broken, just to say that its string is not null and doesn't contain only whitespaces because the empty Trim call will clear them anyway.

Comment: The question does not make it clear when the code needs to trigger. (1) Only on null (2) On null and empty (3) On null, empty, and only containing whitespace. OP is directly asking for (1), but his code suggests that he's looking for (3). The discussion in comments is not meaningful (edit: as a definitively correct answer) unless we know if OP wants 1, 2 or 3; since the suggested code handles these cases differently.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing with `null` is the way to check for it. However in your code, if you have not gotten already a `NullReferenceException` when calling `Trim` then your string is not null.

Might be that you are looking for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TempDayValues[j]))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Found Null");
     TempDayValues[j] = TempDayValues[j - 1];
}
```

If you first want to check if it is null and have one behavior and a different if it is empty/white space:

```
if(TempDayValues[j] == null)
{
    // code
}
else if(TempDayValues[j].Trim() == string.Empty)
{
    // code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question, while valid, is missing an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish. Since you've only asked about null checking; my answer only focuses on the null checking that is performed in your code snippet.

There are a few things to remark about your code that I think will help you understand the situation better.

```
String Temp = TempDayValues[j].Trim();
```

It's interesting to see that you have already called `.Trim()` on the string. If `TempDayValues[j]` was null, this would throw an exception. You can't call methods on null values (you also can't access properties and fields on a null value).

If your application is not throwing an exception; which I assume it is not as you have not mentioned it; then you have implicitly already "proven" that your string is not null. Because you would get an exception otherwise.

Also note that `.Trim()` will never make something null. Since you are only interested in checking if `TempDayValues[j]` is null (and potentially overwriting the value, but never **using** the value); it is functionally irrelevant to use `.Trim()` for the purpose of null checking.

Let's assume for the rest of the explanation that it is possible for your string to be null; even though `.Trim()` has made it impossible in your example.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Temp))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Found Null");
     TempDayValues[j] = TempDayValues[j - 1];
}
```

Your if block will be executed if your string is null, *but also if it is empty*. You are, after all, calling the method string.IsNull**OrEmpty**(). An empty string is a string that is not null, but also does not contain any characters.

So a more correct message would be "found null or empty string".

```
if(Temp == null)
{
   //code here
}
```

While this is a valid method of checking for null; the if block will not execute if your string is empty. This might be what you are looking for. In most cases, I would expect `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to be more suited; but I'm not aware of the specific purpose of your code.

Here, it would be correct to say that you "found null" and NOT an empty string.

---

That being said; what is the answer to this problem?

This isn't easy to answer; as you've not explained the intention of the code snippet. I am going to offer a code improvement, it's the best I can give you without more info.

```
string Temp = TempDayValues[j];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Temp)) //use Temp == null here if you don't want it to trigger on empty strings.
{
     Console.WriteLine("Found Null or empty string");
     TempDayValues[j] = TempDayValues[j - 1];
}
```

**edit** If you also need this if block to be executed for cases where your string is not null, not empty, but it only contains whitespaces; then it is relevant to call `.Trim()`. In that case, change your if block to:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Temp) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Temp.Trim()))
```

If Temp is null, only the left operand will be executed (because it makes the evaluation result `true` regardless of the right operand).
The right operand will be executed **only if your string is not already null or empty**. In that case, it allows you to check for a string that contains only whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks all. Your comments helped me realize there must be a string there. Can you believe the field in the data held the string "null" !!. Confused me for days. I will always be learning